# Reference an object property that has "." in it's name

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm attempting to reference an object property that has a `.` in the name. So, for example, in `fdb` if I have an object:

MyObject
  target.property

If I attempt to "print":

```
fdb> print MyObject.target.property
```

I get:

```
Variable target.property unknown
```

How do I access this property and look at it's contents given that it's name is `target.property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to have `.` as part of a property name, but it can be gotten by:

```
var val = MyObject[ "target.property" ]
```

That is called "array notation".  It is slower and buggier than the correct way to address a property.  It also allows for the introduction of a number of potential bugs and difficulties in diagnosis but, in cases where you don't have control of the input, it will be sufficient.

Comment: Agreed, having a property name with a dot in it is bad practice, and should be avoided.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks cwallenpoole. Much appreciated! Yes, not the best practice, but in this case we don't have control over the input. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

`MyObject["target.property"]`